# изменение элементов при нажатии на добавление файла input

Tags: javascript, html, css, события, input

Пытаюсь изменить стиль элементов при нажатии на другой элемент, который включает input

Суть в том что есть например 2 элемента(дива), которые относятся к input, чтоб можно было добавить файл и при нажатии и добавлении фала должна появиться галка(картинка), если элемент не выбран галочка не появляется. Получилось сделать только, чтоб галочка отображалась на всех элементах, **либо галочка отображается при повторном нажатии на элемент - что-то не так с последовательностью событий**(( Код прилагаю

```
 <div class="card__images">
          <label  for="file-input" > 
          <div id="scan" class="card__image" style="margin-right: 12px">
            <img class="card__round" src="./images/round.png" alt="round" />
            <div class="card__plus"></div>
            <div class="card__items">
              <img class="card__num" src="./images/1.png" alt="1" />
              <img class="card__check" src="./images/chek.png" alt="chek" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </label>
          <label  for="file-input" > 
            <div id="scan" class="card__image">
              <img class="card__round" src="./images/round.png" alt="round" />
              <div class="card__plus"></div>
              <div class="card__items">
                <img class="card__num" src="./images/2.png" alt="2" />
                <img class="card__check" src="./images/chek.png" alt="chek" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </label>
          <input id="file-input" type="file" onchange="kek()"  />
        </div>
```

**JS

```
const scan = document.querySelectorAll("#scan");
const plus = document.querySelectorAll(".card__plus");
const check = document.querySelectorAll(".card__check");
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".card__items");

 function kek() {
  let l = document.getElementById("file-input");
  if (document.getElementById("file-input").value != "") { 
     add();
     console.log('lol1');
  } else  {  remove();
    console.log('lol2'); }
}



  function add()  { 
    scan.forEach((elem, i) => {
      elem.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log('lol3');
        plus.forEach((elem, y) => {
          if (i == y) {
            elem.classList.add("card__pen");
          }
        });
        check.forEach((elem, y) => {
          if (i == y) {
            elem.classList.add("card__check_active");
          }
        });
        items.forEach((elem, y) => {
          if (i == y) {
            elem.classList.add("card__items_active");
          }
        });
       
     
      });
    });}

    function remove()  {scan.forEach((elem, i) => {
      elem.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log('lol4');
    plus.forEach((elem, y) => {
          if (i == y) {
            elem.classList.remove("card__pen");
          }
        });
        check.forEach((elem, y) => {
          if (i == y) {
            elem.classList.remove("card__check_active");
          }
        });
        items.forEach((elem, y) => {
          if (i == y) {
            elem.classList.remove("card__items_active");
          }
        });

           
      });
    });}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я тебя правильно понял, то тебе просто нужно удалить addEventListener
Иначе после загрузки файла ты не добавляешь класс, а просто вешаешь еще одно событие

И ты повесил одинаковые события на свои элементы и они срабатывают одновременно

Еще ты добавляешь классы для всех элементов
Тебе нужно условие по которому ты показываешь/скрываешь галочку